# Trying for draft a 6x6 game board with 2d array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am a rookie and trying to finish my year 1 project " 6x6 reversi chess" and still building the chess board with 2d array atm. I have no idea how to use images as the content in the array to display the game board out and I have no clue to use the mouse-click function let the user play.

I have tried to create a 2d-array but i have to clue what to do next
tried to use "0" as blank space "W" as white chess and "B" as. black

```
       var kboard = new Array (5)
        for ( var i = 0 ;i < 6 ;i++ ){
            kboard[i] = new Array(5)
        }
    kboard[0][0] = "0"; kboard[1][3] = "0"; kboard[3][0] = "0";  kboard[4][3] = "W";
    kboard[0][1] = "0"; kboard[1][4] = "B"; kboard[3][1] = "W";  kboard[4][4] = "B";
    kboard[0][2] = "0"; kboard[1][5] = "0"; kboard[3][2] = "W";  kboard[4][5] = "0";
    kboard[0][3] = "0"; kboard[2][0] = "0"; kboard[3][3] = "W";  kboard[5][0] = "0";
    kboard[0][4] = "0"; kboard[2][1] = "0"; kboard[3][4] = "B";  kboard[5][1] = "0";
    kboard[0][5] = "0"; kboard[2][2] = "0"; kboard[3][5] = "0";  kboard[5][2] = "0";
    kboard[1][0] = "0"; kboard[2][3] = "0"; kboard[4][0] = "0";  kboard[5][3] = "0";
    kboard[1][1] = "0"; kboard[2][4] = "B"; kboard[4][1] = "0";  kboard[5][4] = "W";
    kboard[1][2] = "0"; kboard[2][5] = "0"; kboard[4][2] = "0";  kboard[5][5] = "B";
    for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        for (var j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            document.write(kboard[i][j] + "&emsp;")
        }
        document.write("<br/>");
    }
```

The output is only "0" "B" "W" and prints the whole array out, but I​ cannot use any images instead of that element.

Comment: To be clear: are you asking how to display images in HTML?

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to do in the way you said, but i want to display the 2Darray out like a game board in separate images.
Be like in there are a image to represent "0" "W" and "B" in array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately your question is a bit too broad but I'll try to put you into the right direction.

You're right. A two-dimensional array is the best choice for storing this kind of data. Only the way you're creating it is a bit cumbersome. Instead of countless array[position]=value, you can do it like this:

```
var kBoard = [
  ["0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"],
  ["0", "0", "0", "0", "B", "0"],
  ["0", "0", "0", "0", "B", "0"],
  ["0", "W", "W", "W", "B", "0"],
  ["0", "0", "0", "W", "B", "0"],
  ["0", "0", "0", "0", "W", "B"]
];
```

To finally display your game on-screen you can use plain html  elements in conjunction with a table. I'd recommend using the  element though. As the name immplies it's some sort of artboard you can draw onto using javascript. For simplicity, I'll use plain shapes instead of pictures.

This will create an empty canvas. It's size is determined by tileWidth & tileHeight multiplied by the number of elements inside the array horizontally & vertically.

```
var tileWidth = 64;
var tileHeight = 64;

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = kBoard[0].length * tileWidth;
canvas.height = kBoard.length * tileHeight;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Now we simply loop over the kBoard array and use the position of an element inside the array as our on-screen coordinate multiplied by tileWidth & tileHeight. Furthermore we use the value of an element to draw either a black or a white circle.

```
for (var a = 0; a < kBoard.length; a++) {
  for (var b = 0; b < kBoard[0].length; b++) {

    if (a % 2 == 0) {
      if (b % 2 == 0) {
        context.fillStyle = "#aaaaaa";
      } else {
        context.fillStyle = "#888888";
      }
    } else {
      if (b % 2 == 1) {
        context.fillStyle = "#aaaaaa";
      } else {
        context.fillStyle = "#888888";
      }
    }
    context.fillRect(b * tileWidth, a * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight);
    switch (kBoard[a][b]) {
      case "W":
        context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(b * tileWidth + tileWidth / 2, a * tileHeight + tileHeight / 2, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        break;
      case "B":
        context.fillStyle = "#000000";
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(b * tileWidth + tileWidth / 2, a * tileHeight + tileHeight / 2, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the complete example:

```js
var kBoard = [
  ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
  ["7", "0", "0", "0", "B", "0"],
  ["0", "0", "0", "0", "B", "0"],
  ["0", "W", "W", "W", "B", "0"],
  ["0", "0", "0", "W", "B", "0"],
  ["0", "0", "0", "0", "W", "B"]
];
var tileWidth = 64;
var tileHeight = 64;

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = kBoard[0].length * tileWidth;
canvas.height = kBoard.length * tileHeight;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

for (var a = 0; a < kBoard.length; a++) {
  for (var b = 0; b < kBoard[0].length; b++) {

    if (a % 2 == 0) {
      if (b % 2 == 0) {
        context.fillStyle = "#aaaaaa";
      } else {
        context.fillStyle = "#888888";
      }
    } else {
      if (b % 2 == 1) {
        context.fillStyle = "#aaaaaa";
      } else {
        context.fillStyle = "#888888";
      }
    }
    context.fillRect(b * tileWidth, a * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight);
    switch (kBoard[a][b]) {
      case "W":
        context.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(b * tileWidth + tileWidth / 2, a * tileHeight + tileHeight / 2, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        break;
      case "B":
        context.fillStyle = "#000000";
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(b * tileWidth + tileWidth / 2, a * tileHeight + tileHeight / 2, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        context.closePath();
        context.fill();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sticking to your original code as much as possible, I suspect what you may be wanting to do is display images:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Img

To use this, you would need three pre-existing image files, one for each color. Let's call them

- `W.png`
- `B.png`
- `0.png`

Now, instead of writing the text of your array

```
document.write(kboard[i][j] + "&emsp;")
```

You can instead write out some HTML that will display the image:

```
document.write("<img src='" + kboard[i][j] + ".png' /> &emsp;");
```

Once you have that working, I would suggest looking up html `tables`, and `document.querySelector`, to see how you can use them to make your program even better.

### Further Reading

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Tables/Basics
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks